# Bayesian estimation of tridiagonal covariance

Tags: bayesian, covariance, prior, joint-distribution

I want to estimate covariance of a multivariate normal distribution from data using a Bayesian method. I want to force the result to be tridiagonal. I am looking for an appropriate prior or method. Is there any prior or method for this?

Comment: [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/difficulties-with-a-bayesian-formulation-of-a-model-for-human-timing-data) and my reply to it provide a partial answer. Depending on your experience with Bayes, that may be enough to get you started. Your question is more general because your tridiagonal covariance is fully general, unlike the one in the linked question.

Comment: many thanks Cyan. I am trying to model a sequence of multivariate data in bayesian. In part of my model I want to fit a normal distribution to part of data. I used normal and inverse wishart prior for mean and covariance. However, since number of data is not large enough and dimension of data is large I must decrease number of parameters. Diagonal covariance is not appropriate for my data. I am looking for a prior that keeps the covariance tridiagonal.

Comment: maybe better to start new question.

Comment: A moving average MA(1) model for a timeseries $X_t$ leads to a specific tridiagonal covariance matrix. This reads as $X_t = \varepsilon_t - \theta  \varepsilon_{t-1}$ where $\varepsilon_t$
is Gaussian White Noise and $\theta$ the MA coefficient. The two parameters  $\theta$ and the  variance $\sigma^2_\varepsilon$
can have independent priors, e.g. uniform and gamma.
By specifying a slowly varying $\theta$ and/or variance, you will 
get more general tridiagonal matrices. 
This may be a hint for a hierarchical formulation of your model
if the timeseries formulation makes sense in your context.

Comment: many thanks Yves. I am not sure if I understand your hint. in order to have tridiagonal covariance for my data, elements of data should obey MA(1) model. I have several data X_t for t=1:N. I want to fit a normal distribution on it. X_t~N(mu,Sigma) in a way that Sigma remains tridiagonal. I want to use bayesian method to find mu and Sigma.

Comment: With $X_t = \mu +  \varepsilon_t - \theta  \varepsilon_{t-1}$ you will have a mean $\mu$ and thus $3$ parameters. The covariance matrix has a simple expression, and embeds $2$ free parameters only, instead of $2N-1$ for a general tridiagonal
covariance. Bayesian inference for this model is possible through MCMC. However to
get a more flexible covariance description, you can let $\theta$ vary smoothly  with $t$.

Comment: Sorry @najmeh, the notations of my previous comment are very confusing. If the 
distribution is $p$-dimensional, each $\mathbf{X}_i$ in a sample of size $N$ is a timeseries $X_{i,t}$ with length 
$p$. So we can have $X_{i,t} = \mu_t +  \varepsilon_{i,t} - \theta  \varepsilon_{i,t-1}$.
Anyway, the idea was to deal with $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ through its Cholesky LDL' decomposition
and a simple parametrisation of it. This  does not imply a timeseries interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Some notation: let $\mathbf{Y}$ be a random vector of length $m$ with a $MVN(\mu, \Sigma)$ distribution. For notational simplicity, I'll assume $m$ is even, but nothing hangs on this.

First off, the implications of the tridiagonal covariance: from the properties of the [marginals of multivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Marginal_distributions), a tridiagonal covariance implies that $[Y_1 \,\,\, Y_3 \,\,\, ... Y_{m-1}]^T$ is a vector of independent normal random variables, and likewise for $[Y_2 \,\,\, Y_4 \,\,\, ... Y_{m}]^T$. Assuming this makes sense, and assuming that the prior on $\mu$ is flat, then the link I posted in comments gives the posterior distribution; with appropriate modifications for the fact that your problem has no covariates, we get, let's see...

$$\log\big(p(\Sigma|\mathbf{Y}_1,...,\mathbf{Y}_n)\big) = \log\big(p(\Sigma)\big) -\frac{n-1}{2}\log\big(|\Sigma|\big) -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{Y}_i-\bar{\mathbf{Y}})^T\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{Y}_i-\bar{\mathbf{Y}})\bigg].$$

And ignoring the log-prior term, that, if I haven't gone crazy, is the the kernel of the [inverse-Wishart density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Wishart_Distribution). Of course it *isn't* the inverse-Wishart density because, by definition, it's only supported on the set of symmetric tridiagonal matrices.

As for the prior: your choice of a tridiagonal covariance matrix is very convenient in the sense that the requirement of positive definiteness is trivial to satify: any set of  (marginal) variances $\{\sigma_1^2\, \sigma_2^2, ..., \sigma_m^2\},\, \mathrm{all}\,\, \sigma_j^2 > 0,$ and correlations $\{\rho_1, \rho_2, ..., \rho_{m-2} \},\,\mathrm{all}\,\,\rho_j \in [-1,1]$ will do the job. So it's safe to give the variances independent half-Cauchy priors and the correlations uniform priors. Try that first and see what you get.

If you need more help with the math and/or the implementation of posterior sampling, just tell me in a comment and I'll go into more detail.

Comment: Cyan, many thanks, I got very busy, I hope you are still fresh on the subject.I have the following questions: 1- Is Your derivation of the posterior based on your initial assumption in splitting Y into even and odd samples? If yes, I cannot understand the relation. 2- As far as I understood the posterior your recommended is inverse-wishart. However, sampling inverse-wishart distribution even with your recommended priors does not guarantee that non-tridiagonal elements of covariance remain zero. Have I missed any points you have been trying to make?